# Converting an nisNetgroupTriple String to an Object

Tags: java, parsing, stream

I'm trying to convert [nisNetgroupTriple](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307#section-2.4) Strings which can be of this format:

```
    (host,user,domain)
    (,user,)
    (host,,)
    (host,user,)
    (,,domain)
```

Into a NetgroupTriple object which looks like this:

```
public class NetgroupTriple {
    private String hostname; 
    private String username;
    private String domainName; 

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getDomainName() {
        return domainName;
    }

    public void setDomainName(String domainName) {
        this.domainName = domainName;
    }
}
```

I've got this gross function to do it, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner way using streams.

```
public static NetgroupTriple fromString(String member) {
   
    NetgroupTriple triple = new NetgroupTriple();

    String[] split = member.split(",");
    if(split.length != 3)
        throw new Exception("bad");

    if(!split[0].equals("("))
        triple.setHostname(split[0].replace("(",""));
    if(!split[1].isEmpty())
        triple.setUsername(split[1]);
    if(!split[2].equals(")"))
        triple.setDomainName(split[2].replace(")",""));
    return triple;
}
```

Does anyone know a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there are always encapsulating parentheses, you can remove those right from the start

```
String[] split = member.substring(1, member.length() - 1).split(",");
```

Then, since it appears the order of the incoming `member` is always ("host", "user", "domain") then you can do

```
NetgroupTriple triple = new NetgroupTriple(split[0], split[1], split[2]);
```

So your `fromString()` looks like

```
public static NetgroupTriple fromString(String member) {
    String[] split = member.substring(1, member.length() - 1).split(",");
    if(split.length != 3)
        throw new Exception("bad");

    NetgroupTriple triple = new NetgroupTriple(split[0], split[1], split[2]);
    return triple;
}
```

Which will allow your `NetgroupTriple` to be `immutable`

```
public class NetgroupTriple {
    private String hostname; 
    private String username;
    private String domainName; 

    public NetgroupTriple(String host, String user, String domain) {
        hostname = host;
        username = user;
        domainName = domain;        
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getDomainName() {
        return domainName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't split return an array of size 2 if no domain name is set?

Comment: @PeteyB You are correct. I have updated my solution to add the length check that OP originally had. It appears like OP specifically is looking for something that has all 3 elements given the reference name of `triple` so I'm assuming this is okay for OP. Edit: Oh! You're OP!

Comment: @PeteyB Have you considered serialization? Might be something worth looking into for more elegance

Comment: Now your solution will include the "(" and ")" in the host/domain variable. Serialization would be nice, I'll do some digging. Thanks

Comment: @PeteyB Oh yes, I've edited that. Thank you. I like the Jackson library for serialization, GSON is another one

Comment: No worries, but I think you're back to the problem of split() only returning the  first two Strings when a domain is not set :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works:

```
public NetgroupTriple(String hostname, String username, String domainName){
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.username = username;
    this.domainName = domainName;
}
```

Then the parsing:

```
public static NetgroupTriple fromString(String member) {
    String[] split = member.split(",");
    if(split.length != 3)
        throw new Exception(String.format("Could not convert member to NetgroupTriple: %s", member));

    return new NetgroupTriple(
            split[0].equals("(") ? null : split[0].replace("(",""),
            split[1].equals("") ? null : split[1],
            split[2].equals(")") ? null: split[2].replace(")",""));

}
```

Still not as elegant as I'm hoping for.